# GlassFish deleted Documents

Tags: java, glassfish

I just downloaded Apache Netbeans 14 for a project and then installed GlassFish 5.0.1 . As I was downloading GlassFish 5.0.1 in my Documents folder, my Documents folder looked like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VJrC.png)

Anyone might know what the problem is?
I'm sorry, I am new to StackOverFlow so if i wrote something wrong tell me